# PostgreSQL выборка начиная с определенной даты

Tags: postgresql

Надо сделать выборку, у которых есть дата и чтобы вывело все начиная с даты, например с 2015-01-01. Тип поля Date

Comment: Не поверите `select *  from table where date >= '2015-01-15'`

Comment: Классно! спасибо :)